# How to generate Access Classes for Oracle Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, code-generation, t4, odp.net

I am using c# and currently the idea is getting the Info about stored procedured via sql query

```
select OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, ARGUMENT_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IN_OUT from SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS order by OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, SEQUENCE
```

so one can generate lines like this from the output

```
oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.OracleDbType, parameter.Value, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

and generate the class with T4
My question is can one get the Stored Procedures Properties more cleanly via ODP.Net or is there a completely different better approach

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1):

I searched high and low for a set of T4 templates to generate Oracle stored procedures and data access layers for me and couldn't find anything.  So, I found some examples online and wrote my own.  The link below has the T4 templates files to create basic CRUD stored procedures for every table in a given Oracle Schema and to create their corresponding Data Access Layers in C#.  These procedures and DAL's are setup for use within Oracle's Entity Framework.

You will need T4 Editor, [T4 Toolkit](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/), and ODP.Net installed to use these scripts.  Then, you need to fill in your schema and connection string info, load the T4 templates in Visual Studio and run the .tt files ending with "*Script.tt".  You may need to tweak/modify the scripts for your needs, but maybe these scripts will give you a starting point...

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_OWWs9xWuRQeHVOOUlscWdSZlN0OU9SMS1fWFMxZw

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 0):

[www.metadrone.com](http://www.metadrone.com) can connect to Oracle and generate code based on stored procedures and functions and their parameters.